# Cannot call methods on float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Getting "Cannot call methods on float" when i run this query. I did a search and their are some blank rows in this column but I think that's the issue. I have also tried the following 2 changes and I still get that error. Do i need to put zero's in those blank fields? The Sale_price1 field is a char also.

```
SUM(ISNULL(((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(oe11.SALE_PRICE1) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CAST(oe11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) END)),0))
SUM(CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) AS GROSS
```

Here is the complete code

```
     SELECT DISTINCT
     OE10.ORD_NUMB
    --,COUNT(DISTINCT OE10.0RD_NUMB) 
    ,OE10.ORD_SHIPPED_FLAG
    ,OE10.DATE_SHIPPED
    ,OE10.PROD_CODE
    ,OE10.IND_CODE
    ,ISNULL(OE11.SALE_PRICE1, 0)
    ,OE11.FG_ITEM_DESC
    --,AR10.TRANS_DLR



FROM OE10


LEFT OUTER JOIN 
REPORTING.DBO.dimDate AS DIMDATE ON CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, OE10.RDAT_SHIPPED +5843, 0), 112) = dimdate.DateId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN REPORTING.DBO.dimMisc AS MID ON OE10.PROD_CODE = MID.ProductCode  
LEFT OUTER JOIN OE11 AS OE11 ON OE10.ORD_NUMB = OE11.ORD_NUMB
LEFT OUTER JOIN AR10 AS AR10 ON AR10.JOB_NUMB = AR10.JOB_NUMB 



WHERE OE10.ORD_SHIPPED_FLAG = 'Y'
AND DIMDATE.ISCURRENTDAY = 1
AND MID.BUSINESSUNITNAME = 'Standard Products'
```

Comment: Are any of these things views? I suspect the error is happening in code we can't see. This error usually happens when you give a column an additional name part reference, e.g. `dbo.table.float_column.x`

Comment: No it's just another table

Comment: Can you build the tables on sqlfiddle.com and reproduce the error?

Comment: Yea ill find some time tonight and get that up

Comment: Any of the tables have computed columns?